# Error provide is not defined in Angular 2

Tags: angular

My Angular 2 application gives me the following error:

> angular2-polyfills.js:138 Error: provide is not defined main.ts

Here is my code:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';


bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi:true})]);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**

In Angular2 RC.4 and later `provide` is deprecated. Use object literal syntax instead:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [{provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeOtherService}]) 


@Component({
  providers: [{provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeOtherService}], 
  ...
})
```

**original**

You need to import it. It's exported by `angular2/core`:

```
import {PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, provide} from 'angular2/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it this way from the `angular2/core` module:

```
import {provide, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
```